# Connected to wifi network but no internet after updating ubuntu to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, updates

I just updated ubuntu to 20.04 and now my wifi isnt working even though it is on my other windows machine. Ive also tried ethernet and still didnt work.

I runned `ping google.com` and got `ping: google.com: Temporaraly failure in name resolution`

`ls -al /etc/resolb.conf`: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 39 21:46 1 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolve.conf

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`: No such file or directory

Comment: Hello. Clearly a DNS failure. What have you done to try and troubleshoot this?

Comment: what do you mean, David?

Comment: Can not make it any clearer your DNS is not working. <ping: google.com: Temporaraly failure in name resolution> minus your misspelling.

Comment: well, how can i fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chilli555 edited my question

Comment: What are the contents of the file? `cat /etc/resolv.conf` May we also see: `ip a` You said: "stub-resolve.conf" Please double-check. It should be resolv not resolve.

Comment: for the command ip a its to much for me to wright it since i cant copy it (im on a dif comp)

Comment: Please paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: i cant... my internet isnt working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135430/discussion-between-chili555-and-gamrjake).

Comment: Run `ip a` and also `lshw -c network` and post the results. Those might help.